# jquery correct code format

Tags: jquery

im just curious about this proper code. im happy if some can correct this and explain a little about this.

```
$('.parentmenu:nth-child(1)').addClass('on', function(){
    $(this+'ul').delay(500).slideDown();
});
```

I would like to use the same class element as for **this** referring and add **UL** element to trigger the navigation slide-down. I would like to know what is the correct format.

Or is there a way to shorten this code? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

you can either

```
$('ul',this).delay(500).slideDown();
```

or

```
$(this).find('ul').delay(500).slideDown();
```

either should work.

Answer (score 1):

I have never heard `.addClass()` having any  **callbacks**

This is a **wrong syntax..**

```
.addClass('on', function(){
```

Maybe you are looking for this

```
$('.parentmenu:nth-child(1)').find('ul').delay(500).slideDown();
```

Answer (score 1):

I've never heard of a callback for `addClass()`.

Try this instead:

```
$('.parentmenu').first().addClass('on').find('ul').delay(500).slideDown();
```

Answer (score 1):

I dont think addClass accepts a callback.
A readable line would be

```
$('.parentmenu').addClass('on')
                .children('ul').delay(500).slideDown();
```

Answer (score 0):

yeah it works on single but not inside the addClass. so i refine my codes to this base on your answers.

```
$('.parentmenu:nth-child(1)').addClass('on').find('ul').delay('500').slideDown();
```

This fully worked out the child menu sliding down effect with the adding class on for parent menu hover activation.

Thanks for your help guys.